# Simple Python chat app with sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple client/server chat app in Python with sockets, and eventually turn it into a networked game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.

I found a guide online to create the client/server but I'm having trouble modifying the loops so that each script listens for the other, receives a message, then shows a raw_input that becomes the message sent to the other script, then so on. Here's the code:

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python   

import socket           

s = socket.socket()        
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12221             

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    z = raw_input("Enter something for the server: ")
    s.send(z) 
    print s.recv(1024)
```

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python          

import socket         

s = socket.socket()        
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12221               
s.bind((host, port))   

s.listen(5)

while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   print c.recv(1024)
   q = raw_input("Enter something to this client: ")
   c.send(q)
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: why do you close connection in `while` loop if you want to receive next message ?

Comment: Your server can only handle one connection at a time. How many simultaneous connections should it handle?

Comment: Yo don't want to close the connection. And for both side listening better use threading and put the listen mode on thread as independently. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed. Right now it will work from client -> server -> client -> then the server doesn't prompt for a message again.

Comment: It doesn't prompt because you are blocking on the accept call. You need to separate accepting connections from handling connections. You could put another `while True:` loop before the recv call.

Answer (score 3):

Like @DavidCullen said in the comments, you are halting on the second time through the while loop for the server to accept a new connection.

You can get around that by doing an if-connected check. I also added some print statements so you could clearly debug what is happening.

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12221
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
c = None

while True:
   if c is None:
       # Halts
       print '[Waiting for connection...]'
       c, addr = s.accept()
       print 'Got connection from', addr
   else:
       # Halts
       print '[Waiting for response...]'
       print c.recv(1024)
       q = raw_input("Enter something to this client: ")
       c.send(q)
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12221

s.connect((host, port))
print 'Connected to', host

while True:
    z = raw_input("Enter something for the server: ")
    s.send(z)
    # Halts
    print '[Waiting for response...]'
    print s.recv(1024)
```